# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - How to configure the AppCenter application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am trying to configure and upload the AppCenter installer app.

I already have our actual mobile project deployed on our Worklight Server (running on WAS Liberty profile). Now, we'd like to install AppCenter installer app in order to distribute our app for testing.

I've read through this article here: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp5005.pdf, but didn't see any information on setting up the application descriptor file for the AppCenter Mobile Client.

Currently, my application descriptor file is pointing to localhost. Should this be pointing to our Application Center server URL or our Application Center console? Should it have the same configurations as our mobile app?  And if I need to point it to our console, do I need another context set up for the AppCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, I suggest that you take a look [at the IBM Worklight Information Center topics](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/topics/c_appcenter.html) for Application Center.

As for your questions:

You need not do anything to the AppCenter project (the AppCenter Installer app) other than:

- [Building it](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/r_ac_prereqs_build_client.html) as-is (this varies depending on the platform you build it for) - this means not changing its `worklightServerRootURL` value, is it not required to connect to a Worklight Server (the apps you will install through it - will)
- Uploading it to the Application Center management console
- [Downloading AND installing it](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/c_the_mobile_client.html) to your device
- [Configuring it in-app to point to the Application Center server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/c_the_settings_view.html)

  As for after building your own Worklight project
- Simply [upload the .ipa, .apk or .cod file to the Application Center management console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/t_publishing_worklight_applicati.html)
- [Installing it via the previously-installed AppCenter Installer app](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/appcenter/c_the_mobile_client.html)

You will need to repeat downloading the AppCenter Installer app for each device you want to perform testing on.